# jQuery plugins: variable scope issue between plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scope

I am quite new to writing jQuery plugins, but decided to give it a go. At first I was impressed by the neatness and conciseness of my code but now I am running into some issues with variable scope.

Some code snippets below:

Here I am caching some DOM elements as variables in my own plugin:

```
cacheElements : function () {
    this.$highlighter         = $('div#highlighteranalysis');
    ...
    this.$highlighterText    = this.$highlighter.find('div#highlightertext');
},
```

and I define a function:

```
createValidSelection : function (highlights) {
    ....
},
```

So througout my plugin I can access these variables and functions via this. which is handy. But I rely on a plugin called jquery.texthighlighter in another part of my plugin:

```
makeSelectable : function () {
    var createValidSelection    = this.createValidSelection,
        showNotes        = this.showNotes;
    this.$highlighterText.textHighlighter({
        onAfterHighlight: function(highlights) {
            createValidSelection(highlights);
            showNotes();
        }
    });
},
```

I first declared my createValidSelection object as a regular variable, because this.createValidSelection would now be pointing at the texthighlighter object, instead of my own plugin object.

This works, but I have a feeling there is a much better way.

Also, if I want the method createValidSelection(highlights); to return anything to my plugin, I don't see how this is possible. Returning would happen to the texthighlighter object.

I hope someone can explain to me how to 'switch scope'. I've looked at the .extend() and .proxy() methods, but I am not sure how I would apply them, or even if they are in any related to a possible solution.

Thanks,
Hendrik

PS: If any of this is unclear, this is probably because I don't really know what I am talking about. I am not a professional developer. Please be patient and kind :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just cache your context prior to entering the `textHighlighter` closure scope and call your methods from that variable:

```
makeSelectable : function () {
    var _this = this;

    this.$highlighterText.textHighlighter({
        onAfterHighlight: function(highlights) {
            _this.createValidSelection(highlights);
            _this.showNotes();
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly, many thanks. This enabled me to reference my plugin as _this. in the calls to other plugins, and as this. in the rest of my code. Exactly what I wanted.